# Easiest way to call script for incoming email

Tags: email, scripting, sendmail, procmail

On a Ubuntu server, what's the easiest way to run a script (e.g. Python) when an email is received?

Email filters would be good, but not necessary.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557906/want-procmail-to-run-a-custom-python-script-everytime-a-new-mail-shows-up

Answer (score 0):

Via [procmail](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue14/procmail.html). (note this doc starts by suggesting using the .forward mechanism to invoke procmail from the MDA - its a lot simpler to use procmail AS the MDA)

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running Sendmail you can add an alias to "|/bin/whatever/you/want/to/run".